# Is it possible to write a plugin for Glimpse's existing SQL tab?

Tags: sql, asp.net, performance-testing, glimpse

Is it possible to write a plugin for Glimpse's existing SQL tab?

I'm trying to log my SQL queries and the currently available extensions don't support our in-house SQL libary.  I have written a custom plugin which logs what I want, but it has limited functionality and it doesn't integrate with the existing SQL tab.

Currently, I'm logging to my custom plugin using a single helper method inside my DAL's base class. This function looks takes the SqlCommand and Duration in order to show data on my custom tab:

```
// simplified example:
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlConnection.Open();
object result = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
sqlConnection.Close();

sw.Stop();

long duration = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
LogSqlActivity(sqlCommand, null, duration);
```

This works well on my 'custom' tab but unfortunately means  I don't get metrics shown on Glimpse's HUD:

[image]

Is there a way I can provide Glimpse directly with the info it needs (in terms of method names, and parameters) so it displays natively on the SQL tab?

Comment: So a couple of quick questions... does your lib use Ado under the covers (I'm guessing yes)? If so, does it use any of the DbProviderFactory infrastructure?

Comment: It uses ADO - and I tried to convert the project to use DbProviderFactory but it turned out to be too tricky/time consuming due to the huge number of calls relying on SqlCommand. I spent several hours on it and eventually had to revert. All the DB code does go via a common class so I was hoping I could interface directly with Glimpse in this class and tell it what I'm doing. This is working for me already but only on a custom tab (not the SQL tab).

Comment: There are also some incompatibilities with DbProvider vs bare SqlCommand and SqlConnections (esp with function syntax, bulk copy, and some SQL data types), which make porting the code to DbProviderFactory impractial. Our code also can ONLY work with SQL Server so we have no other need for the Factory pattern currently.

Comment: To to summarise, I have everything working - just not on the right tab :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The following advise is based on the fact that you can't use DbProviderFactory and you can't use a proxied SqlCommand, etc.***

The data that appears in the "out-of-the-box" SQL tab is based on messages of given types been published through our internal Message Broker (see below on information on this). Because of the above limitations in your case, to get things lighting up correctly (i.e. your data showing up in HUD and the SQL tab), you will need to simulate the work that we do under the covers when we publish these messages. This shouldn't be that difficult and once done, should just work moving forward.

If you have a look at the various proxies we have [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/tree/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType) you will be above to see what messages we publish in what circumstances. Here are some highlights:

- **DbCommand**

  - Log command start - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbCommand.cs#L175)
  - Log command error - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbCommand.cs#L182)
  - Log command end - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbCommand.cs#L186)
- **DbConnection:**

  - Log connection open - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbConnection.cs#L243-L245)
  - Log connection closed - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbConnection.cs#L252-L255)
- **DbTransaction**

  - Log Started - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbTransaction.cs#L27-L29)
  - Log committed - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbTransaction.cs#L74-L76)
  - Log rollback - [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbTransaction.cs#L86-L88)
- **Other**

  - Command row count [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbDataReader.cs#L91-L93) - *Glimpses calculates this at the `DbDataReader` level but you could do it elsewhere as well*

Now that you have an idea of what messages we are expecting and how we generate them, as long as you pass in the right data when you publish those messages, everything should just light up - if you are interested [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/Model/MessageAggregator.cs) is the code that looks for the messages that you will be publishing.

---

**Message Broker:** If you at the `GlimpseConfiguration` [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/GlimpseConfiguration.cs#L351-L367) you will see how to access the Broker. This can be done statically if needed (as we do [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbCommand.cs#L108)). From here you can publish the messages you need.

**Helpers:** For generating some of the above messages, you can use the helpers inside the `Support` class [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/Support.cs). I would have shifted all the code for publishing the actual messages to this class, but I didn't think there would be too many people doing what you are doing.

---

### Update 1

**Starting point:** With the above approach you shouldn't need to write your own plugin. You should just be able to access the broker `GlimpseConfiguration.GetConfiguredMessageBroker()` (make sure you check if its null, which it is if Glimpse is turned off, etc) and publish your messages.

I would imagine that you would put the inspection that leverages the broker and published the messages, where ever you have knowledge of the information that needs to be collected (i.e. inside your custom lib). Normally this would require references inside your lib to glimpse (which you may not want), so to protect against this, from your lib, you would call a proxy (which could be another VS proj) that has the glimpse dependency. Hence your ado lib only has references to your own code.

To get your toes wet, try just publishing a couple of fake connection and command messages. Assuming the broker you get from `GlimpseConfiguration.GetConfiguredMessageBroker()` isn't null, these should just show up. Then you can work towards getting real data into it from your lib.

---

### Update 2

**Obsolete Broker Access**
Its marked as obsolete because its going to change in v2. You will still be able to do what you need to do, but the way of accessing the broker has changed. For what you currently need to do this is ok.

**Sometimes null**
As you have found this is really dependent on where in the page lifecycle you are currently at. To get around this, I would probably change my original recommendation a little.

In the code where you are currently creating messages and pushing them to the message bus, try putting them into `HttpContext.Current.Items`. If you haven't used it before, this is a store which asp.net provides out of the box which lasts the lifetime of a given request. You could have a list that you put in there, still create the message objects that you are doing, but put them into that list instead of pushing them through the broker.

Then, create a `HttpModule` (its really simple to do) which taps into the `PostLogRequest` event. Within this handler, you would pull the list out of the context, iterate through it and push the message into the message broker (accessing the same way you have been).

Comment: I'm not having much luck :(  Firstly, GetConfiguredMessageBroker() sometimes returns null, even when it shouldn't be (Glimpse is on and working). Later in the page lifecycle it returns the broker, but by that time it's missed the first command or two.  Even when it's there, it's attaching the parameters to the wrong commands (not sure how that's possible, given they're passed in at the same time).

Comment: The method is also marked as obsolete, so perhaps it's no longer working properly in the current codebase?

Comment: Is this answer still current, given that it's a year on? I was never able to get this working and just wondering if there's now a newer/better way, or if I should persist with your advice given in this answer?

Comment: OK I think I may be getting somewhere! Do you know the purpose behind the connectionID (GUID) in the CommandExecutedMessage() constructor?   I don't think I have this on my bare ADO connection.